# PostgreSQL ERROR: payload string too long

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have the following PostgreSQL table and trigger function implementing history of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ps_counters"
(
  "psid" integer NOT NULL,
  "counter" bigint[] NOT NULL -- This is the array of 256 counters. Upon insertion of new PS all these values must set to array of 256 bigint elements all equal to 0.
);

CREATE TABLE "ps_counters_history"
(
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "timestamp" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT clock_timestamp(),
  "psid" integer NOT NULL,
  "counter" bigint[] NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ps_counters_history_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    table_name text;
  BEGIN
    table_name := 'ps_counters_history_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyy_mm');
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_class WHERE relname = table_name)
    THEN
      EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' || table_name ||
              ' () INHERITS (ps_counters_history);';
    END IF;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name ||
            '(psid, counter) VALUES ($1.psid, $1.counter);' USING NEW;
    RETURN NEW;
  END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ps_counters_history_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ps_counters FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ps_counters_history_trigger();
```

And for some queries above certain limit I have the following error:

```
[2016-12-09 11:04:28.233844] [0x00007fc72ebaa700] [error]: PlayStation (ID: 5; DallasID: MC00-0497): ERROR:  payload string too long
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT pg_notify('addedrecord',json_build_object('dataNew',dataNew,'dataOld',dataOld,'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,'query',TG_OP,'schema',TG_TABLE_SCHEMA )::text )"
PL/pgSQL function ps_counters_history_trigger() line 13 at PERFORM
```

Sample such query is:

```
UPDATE ps_counters SET
counter[0] = 2035400,
counter[1] = 723500,
counter[2] = 5105400,
counter[3] = 750900,
counter[4] = 750900,
counter[5] = 12,
counter[6] = 10,
counter[7] = 2,
counter[8] = 0,
counter[9] = 0,
counter[10] = 0,
counter[11] = 161500,
counter[12] = 0,
counter[13] = 0,
counter[14] = 0,
counter[15] = 0,
counter[16] = 0,
counter[17] = 0,
counter[18] = 0,
counter[19] = 0,
counter[20] = 0,
counter[21] = 0,
counter[22] = 0,
counter[23] = 1901300,
counter[24] = 0,
counter[25] = 0,
counter[26] = 0,
counter[27] = 0,
counter[28] = 723500,
counter[29] = 0,
counter[30] = 0,
counter[31] = 5105400,
counter[32] = 0,
counter[33] = 0,
counter[34] = 5828900,
counter[35] = 5856300,
counter[36] = 2062800,
counter[37] = 0,
counter[38] = 12,
counter[39] = 0,
counter[40] = 0,
counter[41] = 0,
counter[42] = 0,
counter[43] = 0,
counter[44] = 0,
counter[45] = 0,
counter[46] = 1901300,
counter[47] = 0,
counter[48] = 0,
counter[49] = 0,
counter[50] = 0,
counter[51] = 0,
counter[52] = 0,
counter[53] = 0,
counter[54] = 0,
counter[55] = 0,
counter[56] = 0,
counter[57] = 0,
counter[58] = 0,
counter[59] = 0,
counter[60] = 0,
counter[61] = 0,
counter[62] = 0,
counter[63] = 0,
counter[64] = 5,
counter[65] = 0,
counter[66] = 0,
counter[67] = 6,
counter[68] = 0,
counter[69] = 0,
counter[70] = 5,
counter[71] = 5,
counter[72] = 4,
counter[73] = 0,
counter[74] = 0,
counter[75] = 0,
counter[76] = 0,
counter[77] = 0,
counter[78] = 0,
counter[79] = 0,
counter[80] = 0,
counter[81] = 0,
counter[82] = 0,
counter[83] = 0,
counter[84] = 0,
counter[85] = 0,
counter[86] = 0,
counter[87] = 0,
counter[88] = 0,
counter[89] = 0,
counter[90] = 0,
counter[91] = 0,
counter[92] = 0,
counter[93] = 0,
counter[94] = 0,
counter[95] = 0,
counter[96] = 0,
counter[97] = 0,
counter[98] = 0,
counter[99] = 0,
counter[100] = 0,
counter[101] = 0,
counter[102] = 0,
counter[103] = 0,
counter[104] = 0,
counter[105] = 0,
counter[106] = 0,
counter[107] = 0,
counter[108] = 0,
counter[109] = 0,
counter[110] = 0,
counter[111] = 0,
counter[112] = 0,
counter[113] = 0,
counter[114] = 0,
counter[115] = 0,
counter[116] = 0,
counter[117] = 0,
counter[118] = 0,
counter[119] = 0,
counter[120] = 0,
counter[121] = 0,
counter[122] = 0,
counter[123] = 0,
counter[124] = 0,
counter[125] = 0,
counter[126] = 0,
counter[127] = 0,
counter[128] = 0,
counter[129] = 0,
counter[130] = 0,
counter[131] = 0,
counter[132] = 0,
counter[133] = 0,
counter[134] = 0,
counter[135] = 0,
counter[136] = 0,
counter[137] = 0,
counter[138] = 0,
counter[139] = 0,
counter[140] = 0,
counter[141] = 0,
counter[142] = 0,
counter[143] = 0,
counter[144] = 0,
counter[145] = 0,
counter[146] = 0,
counter[147] = 0,
counter[148] = 0,
counter[149] = 0,
counter[150] = 0,
counter[151] = 0,
counter[152] = 0,
counter[153] = 0,
counter[154] = 0,
counter[155] = 0,
counter[156] = 0,
counter[157] = 0,
counter[158] = 0,
counter[159] = 0,
counter[160] = 0,
counter[161] = 0,
counter[162] = 0,
counter[163] = 0,
counter[164] = 0,
counter[165] = 0,
counter[166] = 0,
counter[167] = 0,
counter[168] = 0,
counter[169] = 0,
counter[170] = 0,
counter[171] = 0,
counter[172] = 0,
counter[173] = 0,
counter[174] = 0,
counter[175] = 0,
counter[176] = 0,
counter[177] = 0,
counter[178] = 0,
counter[179] = 0,
counter[180] = 0,
counter[181] = 0,
counter[182] = 0,
counter[183] = 0,
counter[184] = 0,
counter[185] = 0,
counter[186] = 0,
counter[187] = 0,
counter[188] = 0,
counter[189] = 0,
counter[190] = 0,
counter[191] = 0,
counter[192] = 2035400,
counter[193] = 0,
counter[194] = 2035400,
counter[195] = 0,
counter[196] = 2,
counter[197] = 0,
counter[198] = 0,
counter[199] = 0,
counter[200] = 0,
counter[201] = 0,
counter[202] = 0,
counter[203] = 0,
counter[204] = 0,
counter[205] = 0,
counter[206] = 0,
counter[207] = 0,
counter[208] = 0,
counter[209] = 0,
counter[210] = 0,
counter[211] = 0,
counter[212] = 0,
counter[213] = 0,
counter[214] = 0,
counter[215] = 0,
counter[216] = 0,
counter[217] = 0,
counter[218] = 0,
counter[219] = 0,
counter[220] = 0,
counter[221] = 0,
counter[222] = 0,
counter[223] = 0,
counter[224] = 0,
counter[225] = 0,
counter[226] = 0,
counter[227] = 0,
counter[228] = 0,
counter[229] = 0,
counter[230] = 0,
counter[231] = 0,
counter[232] = 0,
counter[233] = 0,
counter[234] = 0,
counter[235] = 0,
counter[236] = 0,
counter[237] = 0,
counter[238] = 0,
counter[239] = 0,
counter[240] = 0,
counter[241] = 0,
counter[242] = 0,
counter[243] = 0,
counter[244] = 0,
counter[245] = 0,
counter[246] = 0,
counter[247] = 0,
counter[248] = 0,
counter[249] = 0,
counter[250] = 1901300,
counter[251] = 0,
counter[252] = 0,
counter[253] = 0,
counter[254] = 0,
counter[255] = 0
WHERE psid = 5;
```

I found that there is limitation in max [notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-notify.html) payload which is 8000 bytes. I don't use `notify` directly in the trigger function but it seems that some of operators use it indirectly.

Is it possible with some kind of work workaround to overcome this limitation?

Comment: `\sf ps_counters_history_trigger()` ?..

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately 8000 seems to be hard limit - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-notify.html

> payload
>
> The "payload" string to be communicated along with the notification.
>
> This must be specified as a simple string literal.
> In the default configuration it must be shorter than 8000 bytes.
> (If binary data or large amounts of information need to be communicated,
> it's best to put it in a database table and send the key of the record.)

See also here - https://github.com/xstevens/pg_kafka

> Before implementing this project I had looked into LISTEN/NOTIFY operations in PostgreSQL. NOTIFY is unfortunately limited to 8000 bytes for the total payload size. I also found several mentions in the PostgreSQL mailing lists that NOTIFY was never intended to send row data; rather it was intended to get change notifications on keys to clean up external caching, etc.

Comment: But which statement exactly triggers notify in my code? I don't use it directly nowhere.

Comment: yes, try `select proname from pg_proc where lower(prosrc) like '%pg_notify%' and proname <> 'pg_notify'` to see if function is called somewhere

Comment: Where to try this? I try it in pgAdmin but it returns nothing.

Comment: hmmm, then please try the same but with `like '%notify%'` - to see if command "notify" is called somewhere

Comment: This founds that I'm using `notify` in `reset_ps_trigger` and `stop_server_trigger` in the same DB, but not in `ps_counters_history_trigger` which is mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Good - look into underlying trigger procedures of these 2 triggers if some of them issues notify with parameters shown in error message. You probably have some complicated chain of actions and error message does not show whole error stack.

Comment: No, there is no such arguments in the two places where I'm using `notify` directly. In this to places I'm using `notify` to communicate some information two C++ server which I'm writing and their payload include only single column value which is not array, but scalar type.

Comment: OK, even better :-D and is this database the only one involved in whole system? Aren't there any actions on other database/ instances? Don't send some audit data from some other trigger somewhere else - another pg db?

Comment: No, this database is the only one involved in the system.

Comment: OK, let's check something else - please try `select * from pg_rules where lower(definition) like '%notify%'`

Comment: It returns empty table.

Comment: OK, so looks like call is not in PG. Any chance you call `PGnotify` from your C++ server? See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-notify.html

Comment: No, I definitely don't call it from the server.

Comment: Hmmm, I like this - let's try something a bit stupid but anyway - isn't there any change you are looking into wrong code? Please run `select proname, pronamespace from pg_proc where proname = 'ps_counters_history_trigger'` to see if you do not have more versions of the function in different schemas.

Comment: It returns 2 column table with 1 row. The first column is `proname name: ps_counters_history_trigger` and the second one is `pronamespace oid: 2200`.

Comment: Hmmm but judging from value in error message `SELECT pg_notify('addedrecord',..` call most likely happens on some insert somewhere. So maybe try both selects into pg_proc and pg_rules again but with `like '%addedrecord%'` - maybe call is constructed in some weird way but this text might be hard coded

Comment: "call most likely happens on some insert somewhere." Really there is insert in the trigger function `EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name || '(psid, counter) VALUES ($1.psid, $1.counter);' USING NEW;`. But how to implement it in different way to overcome the limitation?

Comment: You need to find where this command NOTIFY or pg_notify is called. There are also weird possibilities like whole command string can be stored in table column and executed as string in EXECUTE etc. You need to find it and limit in some way size of `json_build_object('dataNew',dataNew,'dataOld',dataOld,...` output or better store this in some audit table and send only ID of row from audit table in notification.